# Is there any information on the end of life for a Cisco WS-X6748-GE-TX

Tags: cisco

Is there any information on the end of life for a Cisco WS-X6748-GE-TX?

Google is just telling me it is a replacement for a module that has gone end of life.

Comment: This is probably going to be closed as "too localized" since it's incredibly narrow and relevant only for a short period of time. Your best bet is to call your Cisco reseller and ask them. They should be able to answer this without issue.

Comment: Agh, I was worried about that. The answer JakePaulus gave seems to be more broad though, maybe it will help other people?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The End of Life list is here: http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/prod_end_of_life.html

If the item isn't listed yet there, then it hasn't be declared End of Life.

Comment: The above covers the switches but for the latest module EOL notice it is [here](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/collateral/interfaces-modules/transceiver-modules/eol_c51-698060.html) as outlined here [Cisco EOL](http://www.netwerking.co.uk/Cisco-sfp-eol)